# Сортировка объектов коллекций

Tags: c#

Как нужно правильно сделать сортировку объектов коллекций в этом случае?

Есть вот такая структура:

```
public struct EmployeeSalaryDynamicsRowView
{
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }

    public string EmployeeSurname { get; set; }

    public string EmployeePatronymic { get; set; }

    public List<double> AvgSalaryPerYear { get; set; }
}
```

Ее назначение - хранение данных, которые представляют из себя строку таблицы в Excel.

По ходу программы будет создан `IEnumerable<EmployeeSalaryDynamicsRowView>`, который поместиться в отдельный класс, содержащий информацию о соответствующей таблице.

Примерно это выглядит так:

```
public class SomeClassConatinsTableRowsData
{
    IEnumerable<EmployeeSalaryDynamicsRowView> RowsData {get; set;}
     
    ...

    ...
}
```

Информация в таблице имеет следующий вид:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно предоставить возможность сортировки по ФИО - я сделал, и по ЗП(в любом порядке).

Понятное дело, что сортировать просто диапазон ячеек(с зп) таблицы не подходит.

Что я пробовал:

1. Вариант, в котором ловлю `System.ArgumentException: По крайней мере в одном объекте должен быть реализован интерфейс IComparable..`:

`tableRowViewsData.OrderByDescending(d => d.AvgSalaryPerYear)`

`tableRowViewsData` - переменная типа `List<EmployeeSalaryDynamicsRowView>`, которая содержит готовую выборку.

2. Пытался реализовать `IComparable` для `EmployeeSalaryDynamicsRowView`, но так и не понял, как именно нужно сравнивать.

P.S. для работы с Excel использую EPPlus.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы передаете значение списка когда нужно передать сравнимые величины попробуйте передать среднее по списку зарплат [Average()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.average?view=netcore-3.1), или что-то подобное которое вернет единственное значение для списка (Count, First, Min, Max ..... )

```
tableRowViewsData.OrderByDescending(d => d.AvgSalaryPerYear.Average())
```

для пустого сделайте так

```
   tableRowViewsData.OrderByDescending(d => d.AvgSalaryPerYear != null ? d.AvgSalaryPerYear.Average(): 0)
```

если сортировка не такая как нужно посмотрите в сторону других функций

```
tableRowViewsData.OrderByDescending(d => d.AvgSalaryPerYear.Last())
```

Comment: Практически правильно работает, кроме такого момента: есть строки, где в каком-то году пустое значение в excel, а в коллекции - это -1 и зарплата типа double, тогда это строчка после сортировки как вы указали в ответе находится "не на своем месте".

Comment: @IAMLERNCSHARP добавил условие для пустого. И если ответ помог не забудьте пометить как полезный

Comment: Все равно эта строчка не хочет становиться в нужное место.

Comment: Какое оно должно быть? и где оно сейчас

Comment: Добавил в вопросе картинку

Comment: У вас null в конце потому что сортировка по убывании и в конце у вас 0. Если хотите как нибудь по другому нужно узнать желаемое положение

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112734/discussion-between-aziz-umarov-and-iamlerncsharp).